# How do I start the Windows 8 Phone Emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I installed the Windows 8 Phone SDK and I have VS2012 installed.  How do I start the WP8 emulator in VS2012 ?

Answer (score 1):

You create new Windows Phone project on Visual Studio and press F5

Answer (score 1):

First create the new project and build the project,output window shows project is build successfully and then select the emulator type it shows below the menu bar and then press run button near emulator type